# Migrating from vue.config.js with pages to vite.config.js

Tags: vuejs3, vite, rollupjs

I only used Vite with the default settings so far, but now I am trying to migrate an old Vue 2 project to Vue 3 and trying to use Vite instead of webpack.

I have the following vue.config.js (excerpt)

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    filenameHashing: false,
    outputDir: 'src/main/resources/public/clientlibs/vue-dist',
    css: {
        extract: false,
    },
    pages: {
        'attachments': {
            entry: 'src/vue/pages/attachments/main.ts',
            chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'attachments'],
        },
        'base': {
            entry: 'src/vue/pages/base/main.ts',
            chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'base'],
        },
        'templates': {
            entry: 'src/vue/pages/templates/main.ts',
            chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'templates'],
        },
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            libraryExport: 'default',
            filename: '[name].js',
            chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].js',
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/vue'),
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Reading the documentation I can use this for the vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: [
            {
                entry: 'src/vue/pages/attachments/main.ts',
                fileName: 'attachments',
            },
            {
                entry: 'src/vue/pages/base/main.ts',
                fileName: 'base',
            },
            {
                entry: 'src/vue/pages/templates/main.ts',
                fileName: 'templates',
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

But how do I manage to have the `chunk-vendors` (3rd party plugins) and `chunk-common` (own shared code) extracted as well with proper tree shaking?
Also relevant how does the `rollupOptions` look like to have something similar as the `configureWebpack` section?

Comment: You ever found a solution for this? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: @Darkade Sorry, but no. I am also no longer working at the same company where I was trying this so I don't even have access to the code anymore

Comment: thank you anyway! My workaround was having multiple vite.config.js files. not ideal but working without problems